# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Could not find specified column in results using n-hibernate

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-4, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I am new to fluent n-hibernate.

I am using fluent nHibernate to connect to the MYSQL Database in my application. The Mapping class for the result set is declared as below:

```
public class ProcResult
    {
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Price { get; set; }
        public virtual int AddressID { get; set; }

        public virtual string Address { get; set; }
        public virtual string Pincode { get; set; }

    }
```

I have created a routine(Procedure) in MY SQL as :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `testProc`()
BEGIN
    select  a.ID, a.Name, a.Price, a.AddressID, b.Address, b.Pincode from expediads a join adresses b on a.addressid=b.id;
END
```

The hbm.xml file is for routine(stored procedure) is :

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="TestHBN">  
  <sql-query name="testProc">
    <return alias="PR" class="TestHBN.Models.ProcResult, TestHBN">
      <return-property name="ID" column="ID"/>
      <return-property name="Name" column="Name" />
      <return-property name="Price" column="Price" />
      <return-property name="AddressID" column="AddressID" />
      <return-property  name="address" column="address" />
      <return-property  name="pincode" column="pincode" />
    </return>
    Call testProc;
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Also this is the mapping for the result-set class:

```
public class ProcResultMap : ClassMap<ProcResult>
{
    public ProcResultMap()
    {

        Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("ID");
        Map(x => x.Name).Column("Name");
        Map(x => x.Price).Column("Price");
        Map(x => x.AddressID).Column("AddressID");
        Map(x => x.Address).Column("Address");
        Map(x => x.Pincode).Column("Pincode");
    }
}
```

The stored procedure returns data from two tables "expediads" and "adresses". But I want the result-set to be stored in custom class as declared as "ProcResult" here.

I am getting following error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Could not find specified column in
>   results: Address2_0_

Thanks,
Saloni

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you want to declare the ID as an identity column, as it is not generated as part of the stored procedure.  Try simply defining it as an id column.

```
      Id(x => x.ID).Column("ID");
```

Comment: How are you calling the stored proc? It should be through a named query like Session.GetNamedQuery("testProc");

Comment: I am calling the stored procedure as
 var list = session.GetNamedQuery("testProc").List();

Comment: if i donot declare the ID as an identity column, then i got an error message: "The entity 'ProcResult' doesn't have an Id mapped. Use the Id method to map your identity property. For example: Id(x => x.Id)."

Comment: In that case try removing the GeneratedBy.Identity() from it.

Comment: I have removed the GeneratedBy.Identity() from it, but it still give me same error: 
Could not find specified column in results: Address2_0_